# SRID in ST_Geometry fails to update with ‘Define Projection’ but Esri feature class CRS does update

Tags: arcgis-pro, sql-server, st-geometry

I need to re-define (not reproject) a CRS for a feature class in an enterprise geodatabase (SQL Server).  When I use the 'Define Projection' in AGS Pro (2.9.5), the CRS shown in Esri states the proper WKID for the new projection, however, in the Geometry Spatial Type, the SRID is still listed as the old SRID.  The behavior seems fine, except if I try and make a spatialized view, then the old SRID seems to be pulled across.  Also I assume if you did any spatialize queries on the SQL side you would be using the old SRID.  Is this a bug in the Esri tools or is the SRID static in the SQL table and cannot be updated?

[image: CRS ID Mismatch]